# nuxt-gmaps marker not draggable

Tags: nuxt.js

I am using nuxt-gmaps in my nuxt project. I have a marker at locations[0] and the map displays with the marker in the correct location on the map. The map is disaplayed in a component:

```
<GMap
     :center="{ lat: locations[0].lat, lng: locations[0].lng }"
     :zoom="10"
 >
     <GMapMarker
         :position="{
             lat: locations[0].lat,
             lng: locations[0].lng,
         }"
         :draggable="true"
         @dragend="updateCoordinates"
     />
 </GMap>
```

But I can't drag the marker. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`GMapMarker` component implementation](https://gitlab.com/broj42/nuxt-gmaps/-/blob/master/components/GMapMarker.vue#L32) underlying marker options are expected to be passed via `options` props, so to make a marker draggable, it needs to be initialized like this instead `:options="{ draggable: true}"`

For example:

```
<GMapMarker
      :options="{ draggable: true}"
      v-for="location in locations"
      :key="location.id"
      :position="{ lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng }"
      @click="currentLocation = location"
/>
```